# Standard loopholes only

Tags: code-golf, file-system

So, you're browsing Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, and you see a new challenge. The author (*gasp*) forgot to say "No standard Loopholes". You decide to take advantage of this situation, and you read the answer from a file/network. However, you need to make sure that your answer is actually shorter than the legitimate answers, so you golf it, too.

## The Challenge

Write a complete program that prints out the contents of the file `definitelynottheanswer.txt` to STDOUT. This text file only contains valid ASCII characters. Alternatively, the program can get the file location from STDIN or command line args. The only input allowed is the file location if you choose to get the location from the user; otherwise, no input is allowed. There is no reward for getting the file location from the user, but the user input of the file location does not count against the byte total (in other words, `definitelynottheanswer.txt` wouldn't be included in the byte score).

The program must not write to STDERR.

### Bonus

Retrieve the file from the internet *instead* of a file (the URL must be user-supplied). **Reward: multiply source length by 0.85**

## Scoring

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score,`program length (bytes) * bonus`, wins.
- No (other) standard loopholes.
- If the language does not support reading files from disk, it cannot be used (sorry).

Comment: So the task is... read a file?

Comment: No- it's "getting the solution from an external source" </s>.
This idea sounded a lot better when I was writing it...

Comment: I'll try writing my next one earlier than 11 pm

Comment: I recommend using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges. That way you can get feedback before the challenge is posted.

Comment: It should be noted that if a poster doesn't say "No standard loopholes" in their question, they are still forbidden by default unless the OP explicitly allows them.

Comment: How many *only use standard loopholes* have their been in the past? It seems like there have been many

Comment: @BetaDecay I searched it and there wasn't anything similar in the first few pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [tag:underhanded].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically like code-trolling, but without the tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## GNU sed, 0 bytes

Even better..

Comment: Right tool for the job.

Comment: Well, this is the shortest it can go...

Comment: @DanielM. No, you could make one that's so short it closes the console window, which would make it -1 bytes... not really

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 7 bytes * .85 = 5.9 bytes

```
curl $1
```

zzz

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 2 bytes * .85 = 1.7

```
'z
```

Does not work online.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 6 bytes

```
cat $1
```

Provide filename as a command line argument. Probably breaks if the argument contains spaces or newlines or weird chars or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 1.7 bytes

```
qg
```

For security reasons, this does not work in the online interpreter.